# Help understanding the control circuit of a gas discharge tube

Tags: discharge, tube

I'm trying to interpret exactly how you get this famous IxU curve of a gas discharge tube you can find on several places, including the [Wikipedia page about electric discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_discharge).

[image: Glow discharge current-voltage curve]

<sub>Image - [Original work: WikigianThis version: Chetvorno](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Glow_discharge_current-voltage_curve_English.svg), [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), via Wikimedia Commons</sub>

It's from my understanding that, at least in the beginning, it doesn't make sense that you'd be using a current-regulated source, but rather a voltage-regulated source. You'd be setting the voltage to increasing values and reading the output current as you do.

I say that both because of the low order of magnitude of the currents in the dark discharge region, and because this discharge depends on external ionization, not being self-sustaining.

But, that only makes sense until you reach the breakdown voltage and a glow discharge begins.

Then the impedance of the gas tube starts falling quickly and, if you source kept behaving as a voltage source, the current would quickly jump.

What I imagined is that I could achieve this here could by having a voltage regulator followed by a current regulator.

Initially, I'd set the current setpoint to the value at the very breakdown (1 μA), and I'd slowly increase the voltage setpoint, measuring the output current until it stops increasing.

When that happens, both output current and output voltage will stop increasing and get stuck in the D point in the graph, due to the current regulator.

Before I start increasing the current setpoint, I must put the voltage setpoint in at least 1 kV, so it won't limit the output afterwards, before the glow discharge to arcing transition happens.

Only then I can do the rest of the graph by increasing the current setpoint and reading the voltage in the output.

My point isn't that this is impossible, it's only that this requires knowing the current at breakdown, plus the glow discharge to arcing transition voltage before I even begin.

So I'm in doubt if this is how they actually got those readings.

Do anyone knows how that control is usually made?

Comment: You can plot the B-D curve by setting an upper voltage limit and ramping the current setpoint.  (Given the very low currents below D, it might be easier in CV mode anyway, though I don't also know if the B-D curve ever has a negative slope.) Does this help any? (Or if this is the answer, let me know and I can move it there.)

Comment: user2, What would happen in this case (your curve, as shown) if you had a voltage source of \$800\:\text{V}\$ and a voltage source resistance of \$470\:\text{k}\Omega\$?

Comment: user2, If you want to reproduce the entire curve you will need a variety of equipment. 20 orders of magnitude current measurement isn't readily found. Worse, it's *very hard* to make measurements down into 100's of attoamps, as the curve appears to suggest. An IC package has a bulk impedance on the order of 10^11 so even a few stray mV alone would leak that much current near the low end there. So the curve is a composite from various experimental setups. How would you approach it?